# Data Channel Port Range box in IIS Manager is disabled

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, iis, windows-server-2012, ftp

I'm setting the FTP on IIS on my Amazon. I already make it work and can connect if I'm directly on the Amazon server. When I connect from outside, I can connect and accept login, but I cannot list the folder files.

I'm following the instructions here:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/using-the-ftp-service/configuring-ftp-firewall-settings-in-iis-7

In this image show you need to enter the port so passive mode works.

[image]

But in my PC this field is not editable.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

As you can see on the first screenshot:

[image]

And as is mentioned also [in the page you link to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/using-the-ftp-service/configuring-ftp-firewall-settings-in-iis-7#step-1-configure-the-passive-port-range-for-the-ftp-service):

> Go to IIS 7 Manager. In the Connections pane, **click the server-level node in the tree**.

I.e. the option can be set on server-level node only (for all sites on the server).

Not per FTP site:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to open your Amazon ftp ports and ranges like this:

[amazon ports setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWFCy.png)

Comment: And the 1024-65535 range is important to make ftp work properly in passive mode

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, I meant to warn that no matter what you put on IIS, Amazon blocks all traffic through it's firewall by defaut so that you need to properly open firewall ports like you can see on the image in this link (https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWFCy.png). Sorry if I wasn't clear about that.

Comment: Ironic how this solved my issue. I already have the specific ftp port added to AWS' whitelist. But it didn't pass through, I edited it to a range of all the ports 0-65535 and it worked. When I reverted it to only whitelist 211, it worked still.